# IOS 7 - Google Calendar - Fantastical edit mode shows GMT timezone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iphone-5, ios-7.  I use fantastical 2 to manage multiple google calendars.  When I create an event the event is created in my **LOCAL** time-zone (pst).  When I view the event the event is displayed in my **LOCAL** timezone.  However, when I want to edit the event, the time shows up in **GMT**...

Originally Time Zone Support was turned off.

Then I turned it on, and the Time Zone shows correctly (Vancouver).  However, when I go to edit an event it still shows as GMT.

Could you please help me with this...I don't think I can continue to use the software as is...

Please note that I'm NOT on ios-8, I'm on version 7.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

GMT, also called UTC or Zulu time.

Is the basis time (zero) for all time zones clocks world wide.

When the Time Zone Support is turned on, the Calender will rightly so show the GMT for you to decide which time zone is to be used.

It has to do that logically, since you are on time zone support (means automatic switching the time zone) if you travel. So you have to tell it which time zone to use as fix point for that event.

Let me try to make it clearer:

You set a meeting for the Vancouver time at 8:00.
Now you travel to New York and the Calender will automatically move that time to New York time, if the time zone support is turned on, if it is not turned on you would miss that meeting reminder, since it will still show as Vancouver time.

You can either leave it on, and choose the time zone, or turn off the time zone support. If you do not travel outside your PST time zone you do not need the time zone support.

But...there is always a "but".

If you have meeting attendees from different time zones, and not always up to speed of the time differences, calling a meeting at 16:00 Vancouver time with someone in NY would mean 19:00 for them. Here is where the time zone support comes handy for you to look up.

In your Fantastical 2 you can turn it on/off here:

[image: fantastical 2]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...maybe I wasn't clear in my problem statement, this issue happens regardless of when the time-zone is on or off.